# Yahhoo Finance to get Growth Rate

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

I am following [this](https://themakingofamillionaire.com/how-to-create-your-own-stock-tracker-with-google-sheets-cd31193145bb) in order to determine aapl  5 year growth rate and insert into a google sheet. It works fine for calculating basic share price e.g this `=IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL&.tsrc=fin-srch","//*[@id='quote-header-info']/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[1]")`

However when using the same process to calculate 5 year growth rate (which can be seen on [this](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/analysis?p=AAPL) page (and image below) the process doesnt work and google sheets throws an error (Resource at URL not found). This is the formula I am using `=IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/Aapl/analysis","//*[@id='Col1-0-AnalystLeafPage-Proxy']/section/table[6]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]")`

Any idea why and if this is possible ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We are at the mercy of a company changing their websites and sometimes what used to work stops working. I could not even get the first one to return data that you stated worked.

[image]

Check out this sheet that I saw somebody post here, I am not sure it has the specific stats you want. I have also not studied this sheet closely, but it does use json and a small script to work it's magic.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_YfvUIvVLjCqKpGuWM3TYqT1HEco0UascTZcyR2fqjI/edit#gid=896982005

Feel free to make a copy.

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want the next 5 year growth :

```
function growthEstimate(code){
  var url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+code+'/analysis'
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/(?<=root.App.main = ).*(?=}}}})/g) + '}}}}'
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  return data.context.dispatcher.stores.QuoteSummaryStore.earningsTrend.trend[4].growth.fmt
}
function test(){
  Logger.log(growthEstimate('AAPL'))
}
```